# Users using Perl script to bypass Squid Proxy

Tags: proxy, perl, squid, bypass

The users on our network have been using a perl script to bypass our Squid proxy restrictions. Is there any way we can block this script from working??

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

########################################################################
# (c) 2008 Indika Bandara Udagedara
# indikabandara19@gmail.com
# http://indikabandara19.blogspot.com
#
# ----------
# LICENCE
# ----------
# This work is protected under GNU GPL
# It simply says
# " you are hereby granted to do whatever you want with this
# except claiming you wrote this."
#
#
# ----------
# README
# ----------
# A simple tool to download via http proxies which enforce a download
# size limit. Requires curl.
# This is NOT a hack. This uses the absolutely legal HTTP/1.1 spec
# Tested only for squid-2.6. Only squids will work with this(i think)
# Please read the verbose README provided kindly by Rahadian Pratama
# if u r on cygwin and think this documentation is not enough :)
#
# The newest version of pget is available at  
# http://indikabandara.no-ip.com/~indika/pget
#
# ----------
# USAGE
# ----------
# + Edit below configurations(mainly proxy)
# + First run with -i <file> giving a sample file of same type that
# you are going to download. Doing this once is enough.
# eg. to download '.tar' files first run with
# pget -i my.tar ('my.tar' should be a real file)
# + Run with
# pget -g <URL>
#
#
########################################################################




########################################################################
# CONFIGURATIONS - CHANGE THESE FREELY
########################################################################

# *magic* file
# pls set absolute path if in cygwin
my $_extFile = "./pget.ext" ;

# download in chunks of below size
my $_chunkSize =  1024*1024; # in Bytes


# the proxy that troubles you
my $_proxy = "192.168.0.2:3128"; # proxy URL:port
my $_proxy_auth = "user:pass"; # proxy user:pass


# whereis curl
# pls set absolute path if in cygwin
my $_curl = "/usr/bin/curl";




########################################################################
# EDIT BELOW ONLY IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
########################################################################

use warnings;
my $_version = "0.1.0";

PrintBanner();
if (@ARGV == 0)
{
        PrintHelp();
        exit;
}

PrimaryValidations();

my $val;
while(scalar(@ARGV))
{
        my $arg = shift(@ARGV);
        if($arg eq '-h')
        {
                PrintHelp();
        }
        elsif($arg eq '-i')
        {
                $val = shift(@ARGV);
                if (!defined($val))
                {
                        printf("-i option requires a filename\n");
                        exit;
                }
                Init($val);
        }
        elsif($arg eq '-g')
        {
                $val = shift(@ARGV);
                if (!defined($val))
                {
                        printf("-g option requires a URL\n");
                        exit;
                }
                GetURL($val);
        }
        elsif($arg eq '-c')
        {
                $val = shift(@ARGV);
                if (!defined($val))
                {
                        printf("-c option requires a URL\n");
                        exit;
                }
                ContinueURL($val);
        }
        else
        {
                printf ("Unknown option %s\n", $arg);
                PrintHelp();
        }
}


sub GetURL
{

        my ($URL) = @_;
        chomp($URL);

        my $fileName = GetFileName($URL);
        my %mapExt;
        my $first;
        my $readLen;
        my $ext = GetExt($fileName);

        ReadMap($_extFile, \%mapExt);
        if ( exists($mapExt{$ext}))
        {
                $first = $mapExt{$ext};
                GetFile($URL, $first, $fileName, 0);
        }
        else
        {
                die "Unknown ext in $fileName. Rerun with -i <fileName>";
        }




}

sub ContinueURL
{
        my ($URL) = @_;
        chomp($URL);

        my $fileName = GetFileName($URL);
        my $fileSize = 0;

        $fileSize = -s $fileName;
        printf("Size = %d\n",  $fileSize);

        my $first = -1;


        if ( $fileSize > 0 )
        {
                $fileSize -= 1;
                GetFile($URL, $first, $fileName, $fileSize);
        }
        else
        {
                GetURL($URL);
        }

}

sub Init
{
        my ($fileName) = @_;
        my ($key, $value);
        my %mapExt;
        my $ext = GetExt($fileName);

        if ( $ext eq "")
        {
                die "Cannot get ext of \'$fileName\'";
        }

        ReadMap($_extFile, \%mapExt);

        my $b = GetFirst($fileName);
        $mapExt{$ext} = $b;
        WriteMap($_extFile, \%mapExt);

        print "I handle\n";
        while ( ($key, $value) = each(%mapExt) )
        {
                print "\t$key ->  $value\n";
        }
}

sub GetExt
{
        my ($name) = @_;
        my @x = split(/\./, $name);
        my $ext = "";

        if (@x != 1)
        {
                $ext = pop @x;
        }

        return $ext;
}

sub ReadMap
{
        my($fileName, $mapRef) = @_;

        my $f;
        my @arr;
        open($f, '<', $fileName) or die "Couldn't open $fileName";

        my %map = %{$mapRef};

        while (<$f>)
        {
                my $line = $_;
                chomp($line);
                @arr = split(/[ \t]+/, $line, 2);
                $mapRef->{ $arr[0]} = $arr[1];
        }

        printf("known ext\n");
        while (($key, $value) = each(%$mapRef))
        {
                print("$key, $value\n");
        }

        close($f);

}


sub WriteMap
{
        my ($fileName, $mapRef) = @_;

        my $f;
        my @arr;
        open($f, '>', $fileName) or die "Couldn't open $fileName";

        my ($k, $v);

        while( ($k, $v) = each(%{$mapRef}))
        {
                print $f "$k" . "\t$v\n";
        }
        close($f);


}


sub PrintHelp
{
        print "usage:
        -h Print this help
        -i <filename> Initialize for this filetype
        -g <URL> Get this URL\n
        -c <URL> Continue this URL\n"
}


sub GetFirst
{

        my ($fileName) = @_;
        my $f;
        open($f, "<$fileName") or die "Couldn't open $fileName";
        my $buffer = "";
        my $first = -1;

        binmode($f);
        sysread($f, $buffer, 1, 0);
        close($f);
        $first = ord($buffer);
        return $first;
}


sub GetFirstFromMap
{

}

sub GetFileName
{
        my ($URL) = @_;
        my @x = split(/\//, $URL);
        my $fileName = pop @x;
        return $fileName;

}


sub GetChunk
{
        my ($URL, $file, $offset, $readLen) = @_;

        my $end = $offset + $_chunkSize - 1;
        my $curlCmd = "$_curl -x $_proxy -u $_proxy_auth -r $offset-$end -# \"$URL\"";
        print "$curlCmd\n";
        my $buff = `$curlCmd`;
        ${$readLen} = syswrite($file, $buff, length($buff));
}


sub GetFile
{
        my ($URL, $first, $outFile, $fileSize) = @_;
        my $readLen = 0;

        my $start = $fileSize + 1;
        my $file;

        open($file, "+>>$outFile") or die "Couldn't open $outFile to write";

        if ($fileSize <= 0)
        {
                my $uc = pack("C", $first);
                syswrite ($file, $uc, 1);
        }

        do
        {
                GetChunk($URL, $file, $start ,\$readLen);
                $start = $start + $_chunkSize;
                $fileSize += $readLen;

        }while ($readLen == $_chunkSize);

        printf("Downloaded %s(%d bytes).\n", $outFile, $fileSize);


        close($file);

}

sub PrintBanner
{
        printf ("pget version %s\n", $_version);
        printf ("There is absolutely NO WARRANTY for pget.\n");
        printf ("Use at your own risk. You have been warned.\n\n");
}


sub PrimaryValidations
{
        unless( -e "$_curl")
        {
                printf("ERROR:curl is not at %s. Pls install or provide correct path.\n", $_curl);
                exit;
        }

        unless( -e "$_extFile")
        {
                printf("extFile is not at %s. Creating one\n", $_extFile);
                `touch $_extFile`;
        }

        if ( $_chunkSize <= 0)
        {
                printf ("Invalid chunk size. Using 1Mb as default.\n");
                $_chunkSize = 1024*1024;
        }
}
```

Comment: This question is off-topic here and belongs on [sf], but is too old to migrate.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Make Squid a [transparent proxy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should never rely on a non-transparent proxy.

Make sure that traffic out of the network HAS to pass through the proxy and make your firewall block all outgoing traffic except from the proxy.

Your router(s) should then only accept traffic from the firewall.